# What is the most appropriate test for this situation?

Tags: skewness, group-differences

I want to statistically test the mean difference of a continuous variable (let's call this variable 1) between four groups (nominal) in my sample. Variable 1 has a very skewed distribution.
This test also needs to be corrected for three other continuous variables that are certainly confounding variables when it comes to explaining the "variable 1" differences between the four groups.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, regular regression does not assume that the dependent variable is normally distributed, but that the error (as estimated by the residuals) is. SO first test that. If they are skewed, there are a number of options; the two that come to mind first are :

1) Transform the dependent variable, then perform regular regression. For highly right-skew variables try either log or square-root, or look up Box-Cox

2) Perform some variation of robust regression - there are a variety of them out there. Which one is right depends on various things.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is helpful. I should probably also have mentioned (I edited it now) that the variable that divides my sample into four groups is a nominal variable. I don't think that a regression is suited for that?

Comment: A generalized linear model with a non-gaussian response - which one depends on the data - would be a third option.

Comment: @Abdel - doesn't matter if the four groups are determined by a nominal variable, this is a standard regression situation.  Any stats package will handle this by automatically generating three or four "dummy variables".